# How to find if it is a compact operator

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, compact-operators

How to find if it is a compact operator:

$F\colon C[0,1]\rightarrow C[0,1]$ : $x(t)\mapsto \int^1_0 \cos(t^2+s^2)x(s)ds$

Could you please help with this question.

Comment: it is compact because it is integral operator

Comment: Try Ascoli-Arzelá Theorem in the proof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that 
$$F(x)(t)=\cos(t^2)\int_0^1\cos(s^2)x(s)\mathrm ds-\sin(t^2)\int_0^¹\sin(s^2)x(s)\mathrm ds,$$
hence the range of $F$ is contained in the finite dimensional subspace generated by the functions $t\mapsto \cos(t^2)$ and $t\mapsto \sin(t^2)$.

This implies that $F$ is compact.